# How to parse / deserialize JSON returned from rest service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, json-deserialization

I am getting JSON in string format from a URL whose structure is like this, but I am unable to parse it. It's throwing an exception, any idea how to parse it?

Here is the structure:

```
{
   "pathway":{
      "patients":{
         "patient":[
            {
               "patientid":"7703176",
               "name":"Abbot, Bud",
               "status":"Invited",
               "start":"2013-12-07",
               "last":"N/A",
               "engagement":"N/A",
               "drug":"N/A",
               "adherence":"N/A",
               "vitals":"Current",
               "last_appointment":"2013-10-25",
               "next_appointment":"None"
            },
            {
               "patientid":"5089554",
               "name":"Brennan, Bonnie",
               "status":"Connected",
               "start":"2013-12-29",
               "last":"2014-02-01",
               "engagement":"Low",
               "drug":" ",
               "adherence":" ",
               "vitals":"Out of Date",
               "last_appointment":"2013-04-21",
               "next_appointment":"None"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

i am doing like this:

```
public class PathWayWrapper
{
    public pathway pathway { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class pathway
{
    public List<patient> patients { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class patient
{
    public long patientid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string engagement { get; set; }
    public string drug { get; set; }
    public string adherence { get; set; }
    public string vitals { get; set; }
    public string last_appointment { get; set; }
    public string next_appointment { get; set; }
}
```

here is my parsing code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

var Jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PathWayWrapper>(json);

objPathway = Jsonobject.pathway;
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: I formatted your JSON and it doesn't seem to be in a correct format.

Comment: Your JSON is missing these at the end "]}}}", you need to close the array, object, object, object.

Comment: i have corrected it but still i am unable to parse can somebody tell me how i parse it

Comment: You're missing closing braces: 1 `]` for the array,  and 3 `}` for the `patients`, `pathway` and overall scope.

Comment: How are you parsing it?  You should be using `JSON.parse`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse

Comment: Are you trying to parse in C# or jQuery?  What have you tried?  Post your attempt.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com to validate the output of service.

Comment: You can use a [generator](http://http://json2csharp.com/) to test for the validity of your json

Comment: i have posted i am on server side and trying to deserialize json to map on my class object

Comment: @RickS i posted my attempt please see whats the issue?

Comment: Visual Studio's "Paste JSON as classes" are perfect for this sort of thing. They will create POCO objects from your JSON that should deserialise first time..

Comment: @LDJ i didnt got what you are trying to say any example please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The classes into which you're deserializing are incorrect. You are missing the "Patients" class.

When I have JSON and am trying to deserialize it I like to use http://json2csharp.com to generate a first cut at the deserialization classes. It's more accurate than trying to do it by hand.

```
var jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

public class Patient
{
    public string patientid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string engagement { get; set; }
    public string drug { get; set; }
    public string adherence { get; set; }
    public string vitals { get; set; }
    public string last_appointment { get; set; }
    public string next_appointment { get; set; }
}

public class Patients
{
    public List<Patient> patient { get; set; }
}

public class Pathway
{
    public Patients patients { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Pathway pathway { get; set; }
}
```

P.S. The exception you were getting is usually a really good clue that there's something wrong with the way you've defined the deserialization classes.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.Program+patient]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.