# How to convert JSON Response to a List in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This might be a basic question but I am stuck while converting a JSON Response to a List. 
I am getting the JSON Response as,

```
{"data":[{"ID":"1","Name":"ABC"},{"ID":"2","Name":"DEF"}]}
```

Have defined a Class,

```
class Details
{
    public List<Company> data { get; set; }

}
class Company
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Have tried this for converting,

```
List<Details> obj=List<Details>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
   (responseString,     typeof(List<Details>));
```

But this returns an error, saying

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Client.Details]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Kindly help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse / deserialize JSON returned from rest service in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938920/how-to-parse-deserialize-json-returned-from-rest-service-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Deserialize like this:

```
var Jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(json);
```

<strike>using classes generated by json2csharp.com:</strike>

```
var Jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

and your classes should be :

```
public class Datum
{
public string ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

you can always use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate right classes for the json.

Comment: @Hamlet  I know but I added for OP so that he/she is aware of this way also

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `List<Detail>` defined in your JSON.  Your JSON defines *one* `Detail` record, which itself has a list of companies.

Just deserialize using `Details` as the type, not `List<Details>` (or, if possible, make the JSON wrap the single detail record into a one item array).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScriptDeserializer` class

```
string json = @"{""data"":[{""ID"":""1"",""Name"":""ABC""},{""ID"":""2"",""Name"":""DEF""}]}";
Details details = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Details>(json);
```

EDIT: yes, there's nothing wrong with OP's approach, and Servy's answer is correct. You should deserialize not as the List of objects but as the type that contains that  List

Comment: He could use another deserializer, but it there is nothing wrong with the one that he's using, nor does using a different one change anything about the problem that he has or how it should be fixed.